# Unable to write Extension Method for Map<TKey, TValue[]> in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I'm a new Angular/TS user and enjoying using Extension methods. They well worked on standard types but now I'm trying to write one for Map where V will be array but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm trying to do is that extension method will either initialise the map V as array and push the value  or push if already initialised.

```
declare global {
interface Map<TKey, TValue[]>
 {
    SetInArray(key:TKey, value:TValue):boolean;
 }
}


Map.prototype.SetInArray = function<TKey, TValue>(key:TKey, value:TValue):boolean {

let isNew:boolean = false;

if(this.has(key) == false){

    this.set(key, []);

    isNew = true;

}

let items:TValue[] = this.get(key);

items.push(value);

return isNew;
};


export {};
```

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: If we've learned anything from #SmooshGate it is that it is a really bad pattern to modify the built-in objects in JavaScript. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems (aside from the fact that the common wisdom is that [you should not extend native object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes)).  The first is that when you declare a generic interface or type, its type parameter must be a bare name, not a function of some other type.  So you can't have

```
interface Foo<T, U[]> {} // error
```

If you require the second type parameter to be an array, you should use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
interface Foo<T, U extends any[]> {} // okay
```

The next problem is you can't [merge declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) of generic types if you change the type parameters or their constraints in any way.  `Map<K, V>` is already defined in [the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.6/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21) so you can't change it to `Map<TKey, TValue[]>` or `Map<TKey, TValue extends any[]>` or even `Map<K, V extends any[]>`.  You have to just leave it as `Map<K, V>`.

The new method you're adding requires `V` to be an array type in order to make sense.  And you can't constrain `V` in your declaration.  Are you stuck?  No!  Luckily, you can use a TypeScript feature called a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).  The idea is that you can add a parameter  named `this` to the beginning of your parameter list on a function or method.  When you call the method you don't use the `this` parameter, but TypeScript will enforce that you only call that method on an object whose `this` context matches.

Like this:

```
// no error
declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    SetInArray<V>(this: Map<K, V[]>, key: K, value: V): boolean;
  }
}

Map.prototype.SetInArray = function <K, V>(this: Map<K, V[]>, key: K, value: V): boolean {
  let isNew: boolean = false;
  if (this.has(key) == false) {
    this.set(key, []);
    isNew = true;
  }
  let items: V[] = this.get(key)!;
  items.push(value);
  return isNew;
};
```

Let's try it out:

```
const numberArrayMap = new Map<string, number[]>();
numberArrayMap.set("a", [1, 2, 3])
numberArrayMap.SetInArray("a", 4); // okay

const numberMap = new Map<string, number>();
numberMap.set("a", 4)
numberMap.SetInArray("a", 4); // error
// The 'this' context of type 'Map<string, number>' is not assignable 
// to method's 'this' of type 'Map<string, number[]>'. 
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

This is exactly the behavior you want, I think.  Note how `numberArrayMap` lets you call `SetInArray()`, but `numberMap` does not, and the error tells you that even though `Map` does have a `SetInArray` method, you simply cannot call it due to an incompatible `this` context.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: it worked like a charm and explanation helped me to learn generics in more detail. Thank you very much :)